# Realizar merge de PNG/JPEG com GIF usando PHP

Tags: php, merge, gif

Preciso fazer um **merge** de uma imagem em **PNG/JEPG** com alguns gifs e salvar o resultado final como **GIF**.
Eu consigo fazer esse **merge** com o código abaixo, a imagem é salva como gif mas acontece que o gif perde a animação.

```
// No request eu tenho uma imagem JPEG e 2 gifs
$files = $request->file('gif');

$image1 = imagecreatefromjpeg( $files[0]->getRealPath() );
$image2 = imagecreatefromgif( $files[1]->getRealPath() );
$image3 = imagecreatefromgif( $files[2]->getRealPath() );

// Cria uma nova imagem true color
$merged_image = imagecreatetruecolor( 800, 800 );

imagecopymerge( $merged_image, $image1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 800, 800, 100 );
imagecopymerge( $merged_image, $image2, 20, 50, 0, 0, imagesx( $image2 ), imagesy( $image2 ), 100 );
imagecopymerge( $merged_image, $image3, 550, 50, 0, 0, imagesx( $image3 ), imagesy( $image3 ), 100 );

header( 'Content-Type: image/gif' );

imagegif( $merged_image );

imagedestroy( $image1 );
imagedestroy( $image2 );
imagedestroy( $image3 );
imagedestroy( $merged_image );
```

[image: GIF 01][image: GIF 02][image: JPEG][image: Imagem depois do merge]

Answer (score 0):

Conforme *Manual* https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php

- Ao ler arquivos GIF na memória, apenas o primeiro quadro é retornado
  no ponteiro de recurso de imagem.

Você não poderá redimensionar uma imagem gif da forma que faz facilmente com jpeg, bmp ou outros formatos de imagem.

A função imagecreatefromgif () não irá ajudá-lo, dê uma olhada no link abaixo.

http://phpimageworkshop.com/tutorial/5/manage-animated-gif-with-imageworkshop.html

Veja se isso pode ajuda-lo